# Qt Creator unknown module QT:webengine

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I installed Qt5 on Raspberry Pi 4 with Bullseye OS following this guide: https://qengineering.eu/install-qt5-with-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-4.html

I have an app that needs to be modified and when opening the project in Qt Creator I get this error

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT:webengine
```

Tried `sudo apt install qtwebengine5`
`apt search webengine` doesn't show any webengine libraries only some documentations.
How do I get qtwebengine5 to work on Raspberry Pi 4 Bullseye?